# Is pyspark streaming suitable for machine learning/ scientific computing?

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark and have to write a streaming application that has to perform tasks like fast fourier transformations and some machine learning stuff like classification/regression with svms etc. I want to do this in pyspark, because of python's huge variety of modules like numpy, scikit-learn etc. My question is, is it possible to do such stuff in a streaming application? As far as I know, spark uses dstreams. Are these streams convertible to something like numpy arrays or anything similar that can serve as an input for python functions?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark is used to run program/code/algorithm in spark, which are coded in python language.

For machine leaning, spake has MLlib library packages.

For streaming purpose, spark has Spark streaming lib packages

You can explore Storm as well for real time streaming.

Comment: ok, but how can be done both (streaming and machine learning) at once?

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning is process of learn from data. First you train your model and then use that on top of data stream.
Data can be processed as mini, micro or even real time, depends on amount of data it is generating in a particular time.
Flume and Kafka are used to fetch data on real time and store on HDFS or can be fed to Spark with Spark streaming pointing to flume sink.